# iOS 5: UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: not working / ignored

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

As per Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I'm trying to set custom finished selected and unselected images on a UITabBarItem like so:

```
...
DetailViewController *vc1 = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
UITabBarItem *vc1i = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemTopRated tag:100];
[vc1i setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_item_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_item_normal.png"]];
[vc1 setTabBarItem:vc1i];
...
```

Basically what's happening is the TabBar loads up just fine, it just completely ignores the tab bar item customization.

I'm targeting iOS5+

The images are 30x30 transparent PNGs and exist in the project. Can't figure out what I'm overlooking here, but must be something!

This is being called in the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, ala Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: requires iOS 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tab bar item is initialized with the method: `initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:`. But, as the documentation says:

> This method returns a system-supplied tab bar item. The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later.

You should initialize the tab bar item with `initWithTitle:image:tag:`.

```
UITabBarItem *vc1i = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Top Rated" image:nil tag:100];
[vc1i setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_item_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_item_normal.png"]];
```

Comment: Oops, I knew I was missing something simple like that - thanks a lot!

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

If your are trying to achieve displaying of the actual image at the UITabBar then use the following code.

```
[yourTabBarItem setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

and if you want to display image in original condition for the selected then use the following

```
[yourTabBarItem setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

these two are alternative to

```
setFinishedSelectedImage:  withFinishedUnselectedImage:
```