# Using custom selected and unselected images on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to set my own images as selected and unselected images on a UITabBarItem, but no luck. I've tried the following code in the view controller `viewDidLoad`and `viewWillAppear`methods, but neither works:

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_rojo"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"]];
```

What am I doing wrong? I've read also: [iOS 5: UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: not working / ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547669/ios-5-uitabbaritem-setfinishedselectedimagewithfinishedunselectedimage-not-wo), but I've created my UITabBarController on the IB, not programmatically. Is this the problem?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify the images for every tab item. The following code is working for me

```
if ([[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] respondsToSelector:@selector(setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:)]) {

  [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bleble1.png"]];
  [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla2.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bleble2.png"]];
  [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla3.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bleble3.png"]];
  [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla4.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bleble4.png"]];

}
```

Comment: Where should thid code be placed? Can I use it in `viewDidLoad`of one of the view controllers shown by the UITabBarViewController?

Comment: Sure! It works! I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Remember in iOS7 you need to use the SELECTED version of the icons in the storyboard with this code

Comment: Docs say that `setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` is deprecated in iOS7, they tell to use `image` and `selectedImage` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I used this :

[ALTabbar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/altabbarcontroller)

Comment: Thank you, but I was not interested in commercial controls, just want to know how to properly use the `setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage`method.