# How to remove shadow and gloss effect of UITabBarIcon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, ios7

I am trying to remove the gloss effect and shadow of the UITabBarItem on iOS5/6 but somehow I don't get it...
Actually I want the App to look on iOS5/6 just like on iOS7.. Is it possible to remove this gloss effect?
First image is iOS7, second iOS6
[image: iOS7]

[image: iOS6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you could in two ways, one the hard, is change the background image of the tab bar for each selection, you also need to remove titles and images in you view controllers.
 The easy way will be use this method on each tab bar item [`-setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarItem)
Check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547669/ios-5-uitabbaritem-setfinishedselectedimagewithfinishedunselectedimage-not-wo)

Comment: If I use this method on a tabBarItem nothing changes. Even if I try to change the title of the TabBarItem it doesn't changes, although the IBOutlet ist correctly connected in Interface Builder.. edit: I managed to access it now, but It seems that I still have to make to images manually... There is no other way, I guess?

Comment: Hello, the other way is one that used once, composing a new background  to use with tab bar, but is pretty hard and not flexible. I've created in photo editor a background with all elements unselected and each single selected elements. Triggered by one method declared in -tabbarViewControllerDelegate  I used core graphics functions to draw a new background composed by the unselected icons background and the selected one at runtime, but is not very "smart".

Comment: Okay thank you.. I've done it now with the setFinishedSelectedImage:... method and it's working :) thanks

Comment: How to do this on IOS7?  These functions in this answer are deprecated now.

Comment: Good question, but I don't have an answer, looking through the doc it seems that you can only deal with tintColor. Why don't you open a new question?